Trouble finding the general solution to Volterra's integral equation

Solve the Volterra integral equation for $\lambda = 1$
$$ x(t)=\int_0^t (t-s) \cdot x(s) d s+t^3 $$

I am solving it by iterative approximations
$$
K_{n+1}(t, s)=\int_s^t K\left(t, {\tau}\right) K_{n+1}\left(\tau, s\right) d \tau
$$
after the first three
\begin{aligned}
& K_1(t, s)=(t-s) \\
& K_2(t, s)=\frac{1}{6}(t-s)^3 \\
& K_3(t, s)=\frac{1}{120}(t-s)^5\\
&....................\\
& K_{n+1}(t, s)=\frac{1}{(2 n+1)}(t+s)^{2 n+1}
\end{aligned}
the resolvent
$$
R(t, s, \mu)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mu^n \frac{1}{(2 n+1)!} \cdot(t-s)^{2 n+1}
$$
but now I dont know how to continue to get the general solution, for any $\mu$
$$x(t)=t^3+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu^n \frac{1}{(2 n+t)!}\int_0^t s^3 (t-s)^{2n +1} d s.$$
I just solved the case $\mu =1$ where
$$\int_0^t s^3 \cdot \frac{e^{t-s}-e^{s-t}}{2} d s= \int_0^t s^3 \cdot \sinh(t-s) d s =\frac{e^{-t} \left(6 e^{2t} - 6\right) - 2t^{3} - 12t}{2}$$
and  $x(t)=3 \left(2e^t- 2e^{-t}-3 t \right)$
I do not know what to do with the series with $\mu$ (I am not good at series nor integrating)
PS. Answer on Mathematica


Can you just rewrite the $\mu^n$ to bring it in with the $2n+1$ powers? Say $\mu^n = \mu^{-1/2} (\sqrt{\mu})^{2n+1}$?

You can use Cauchy formula for repeated integration to say $\int_0^t (t-s) \cdot x(s) d s=\int_0^t  \int_0^s x(u) d u d s$, so it would become an double integral. This means that differentiating twice gives us $x''(t)=x(t)+6t$ or $x''(t)=\lambda x(t)+6t$. You should be able to solve that.

We can apply the Laplace transform to the integral equation for $t\ge 0$:
$$\mathcal{L}_t[x(t)](s)=\mathcal{L}_t[\lambda\cdot(t\circledast x(t))+t^3](s)$$
$$X(s)=\frac{\lambda}{s^2}\cdot X(s)+\frac{6}{s^4}$$
Hence
$$X(s)=\frac{6}{s^2 \left(s^2-\lambda\right)}=\frac{6}{\lambda  \left(s^2-\lambda \right)}-\frac{6}{\lambda  s^2}$$
and
$$x(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[X(s)](t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[\frac{6}{\lambda  \left(s^2-\lambda \right)}-\frac{6}{\lambda  s^2}](t)=6 \left(\frac{\sinh \left(\sqrt{\lambda } t\right)}{\lambda ^{3/2}}-\frac{t}{\lambda }\right)$$
Hint: The $\circledast$ operator denotes the convolution.
